# How to deactivate a JS code for specific width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link that in normal when I click on it, it gives me a `alert()` *(using jquery).*

HTML:

```
<a class="link" href="www.example.com">link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
    return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 980px)
{
  // In this width, when user click on that link,
  // I want to open www.eample.com
}
```

Now my question is this: How do i determine wether the client's width is less than or greater than 980 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `$(window).width()`

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 980){  
       alert('clicked');
       return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Why `else` is necessarily?

Comment: Also I think you should replace `>=` with `>`, Because in CSS  `min-width: 980px` means both bigger and equal *(I think)*.

Comment: @Sajad sorry my bad .. you r totally right :) .. updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not deactivate JavaScript using CSS, you'd have to use JavaScript and check the width with `$(window).width()`

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 980) {
        alert('clicked');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what you want to do but if i understand correctly you want some javascript code to run when the client's width is smaller/bigger than a certain amount of pixels.

If that's the case you'd have to check within the click callback function whether the clients screen was larger/smaller than 980px.

```
$(".link").click(function () {
  if (window.innerWidth > 980) {
    alert('clicked');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think match media is pretty sweet also:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media (min-width: 980px)');
var link = document.querySelector('.link');
link.href = mq.matches ? "http://www.example.com" : "";
```

**EDIT:**

Oh, as @Oscar points out: If you're worried about the combined **~16%** **market** **share** *(oct/2015)* of IE8/IE9, go with the jquery method detailed in the chosen answer.

Comment: Just beware that it won't work for IE8 or IE9, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Comment: thanks, @Oscar. My ans only covers ~84% of traffic, prob worst case.

Comment: @Todd: Hopefully that is enough because your solution is, in my opinion, the best! :)